# Xamarin thrift pcl Implementation

Tags: xamarin, mono, thrift

I have been trying to find a way to use apache thrift in my Xamarin Forms app but I could not manage since thrift.dll needs System.Web.dll and there is no mono implementation for System.Web.dll. Do you know any workaround  to achieve this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In general, Thrift works fine with Mono, so that's not the issue. As you already found out, the problem starts where the limited capabilities of mobile devices' .NET framework implementations end. Regarding your specific problem: There is a [Windows Phone 7.x project file](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/csharp/src/Thrift.WP7.csproj) around which has these dependencies:

- Microsoft.Phone
- Microsoft.Phone.Interop
- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.Servicemodel.Web
- System.Windows
- system
- System.Core
- System.Xml
- System.Net

The WinPhone7 *.csproj has of course limited capabilities, e.g. there is no server code available for some technical reasons. The compatibility mostly relies on `SILVERLIGHT` being defined, and yes, it may not be perfect, but works Good Enough™. You may try this one, see how far it supports your needs, and what changes need to be made (if any).

As of now, there are no Xamarin-specific things in the code, but you know, this is open source and we always appreciate pull requests or patches, especially valuable ones like this. If you think you could make a [contribution](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute), join the [mailing list](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing) and/or the freenode `#thrift` IRC channel and ask for whatever support you need with this. We will be happy to help you.

Comment: Does it support Xamarin now? I dint see any update on Github for Xamarin.

Comment: What exactly are you missing or found not working with Xamarin?

Comment: I am looking at tutorial code from github to begin with. [The files they have linked](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/af7ecd6a2b15efe5c6b742cf4a9ccb31bcc1f362/tutorial/csharp) have been missing?

Comment: I would suggest to ask the question on the [mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user). It is entirely unclear to me what you mean by "the linked files have been missing" and why you think that Xamarin is somehow special over C#, Mono or netcore/netstd. Maybe the comment function here offers just not enough room to allow you to communicate clearly what you want.